# Creating a GUI that allows uses to modify fixed format column width

Tags: python, pandas, pysimplegui

I'm bringing text files into pandas through PySimpleGUI. Each of the files has columnar data but between them, they might have different fixed format column widths. They're mainly space delimited but occasionally don't! E.G.

```
File 1
H26 5678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
H26      1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
S         1      3001  1                       731513.8 7050176.3   nan         

File 2
H26 5678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
H26      1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
S         1      3001  1                       731513.847050176.37  nan
```

Ideally, it'd be great to replicate something like excels "Data-to-Columns" but I thought even leveraging the idea of "Demo_Table_Simulation.py" which is like a live update and adding in some working code I(?) wrote.

```
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('Dark2')

f_PosKey = sg.popup_get_file('Select Position-Key.txt file:', file_types=(('.txt files','*.txt'), ("ALL Files", "*.*"),))

#Prompt user for column widths
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please enter start and end column width')],
    [sg.Text('HeaderRows. (eg 60)', size =(30,1)),sg.InputText(size =(7,1))],    
    [sg.Text('Position. (eg 1,6)', size =(30,1)),sg.InputText(size =(7,1)),sg.InputText(size =(7,1))],
    [sg.Text('Key. (eg 20, 25)', size =(30,1)),sg.InputText(size =(7,1)),sg.InputText(size =(7,1))],
    [sg.Text('X, (eg 46,55)', size =(30,1)),sg.InputText(size =(7,1)),sg.InputText(size =(7,1))],
    [sg.Text('Y, (eg 55, 67)', size =(30,1)),sg.InputText(size =(7,1)),sg.InputText(size =(7,1))],
    [sg.Text('Elevation, (eg 68, "0")', size =(30,1)),sg.InputText(size =(7,1)),sg.InputText(size =(7,1))],
    #[sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
    [sg.Button('Try Values',expand_x = True) ]
]

window1 = sg.Window('PosKey FixedWidth Splitter',layout,enable_close_attempted_event=True)
while True:
    event1, values = window1.read()
    
    if event1 in (None,'Exit'):
        break
    elif event1 == 'Try Values':
        #Fixed Width Loop
        #default values
        if values[0] == "":
            values[0] = 60 
        #Position
        if values[1] == "":
            values[1] = 8 
        if values[2] == "":
            values[2] = 13 
        #Key
        if values[3] == "":
            values[3] = 18 
        if values[4] == "":
            values[4] = 23 
        #X
        if values[5] == "":
            values[5] = 47 
        if values[6] == "":
            values[6] = 56 
        #Y  
        if values[7] == "":
            values[7] = 56 
        if values[8] == "":
            values[8] = 68 
        #Elevation  
        if values[9] == "":
            values[9] = 69 
        if values[10] == "":
            values[10] = 0 

        #-1 for base0 python count vs text editor
        col_specification = [(int(values[1])-1,int(values[2])-1),
                              (int(values[3])-1,int(values[4])-1),
                               (int(values[5])-1,int(values[6])-1),
                                (int(values[7])-1,int(values[8])-1),
                                 (int(values[9])-1,int(values[10])-1)]

        df_PosKey = pd.read_fwf(f_PosKey, skiprows = values[0], header = None, index=False, colspecs=col_specification)
        try:
            df_PosKey.apply(pd.to_numeric)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            
        df_PosKey.columns = ["Position", "Key", "X", "Y", "Elevation"]

        df_PosKey['Position-Key']=df_PosKey['Position'].astype(str) + df_PosKey['Key'].astype(str)
        df_PosKey['date_recorded'] = f_PosKey.rsplit('.',1)[-2][-6:].replace('_',' ')

        #Is this correct pop-up? if not re-run 
        headings=list(df_PosKey.columns)
        values = df_PosKey.values.tolist()
            
        layout2 = [
            [sg.Table(values = values, headings = headings,
            auto_size_columns=True)],
            [sg.Button('Accept'), sg.Button('Go_Back')]
                  ]

        window2 = sg.Window('Does this Look alright? "Go_Back" to Modify',  layout2)

        while True:
            event2,values2 = window2.read()
            if event2 ==sg.WIN_CLOSED or event2 == 'Accept':
                
                window1.close()
                window2.close()
                break
            else:
                #window2.close()
                break
        window2.close()
window1.close()
```

Let me know what you think. It'd be great to use this as an interface for 'all' types of files.

Edit:my actual question: has anyone made an interface like I'm asking. A fixed format importer?

Comment: "Are" those "'scare' quotes" really "necessary"?

Comment: A monospaced font would fix (like Courier)?

Comment: One piece of advice... always use keys for input and other elements you want to interact with.  This way you don't have to worry about adding 1 in the middle and screwing up the numbering.

Comment: @MikefromPSG Good call on the numbering. It was annoying having to renumber when I added in the header rows. Ty.